# Grammar rule for sequence of blocks of digits that increase in length each repetition

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I want to generate a parsing rule (using ANTLR 4) that defines a repeating chain of binary blocks separated by ':'.

Each block has one digit more than the previous block, starting with two digits. For example:

```
01:010:0001:01010 ...
```

The chain can have an arbitrary number of these blocks.

Right now I have defined the rule as:

```
BIN : [0-1]+ ;
connections : BIN (':' BIN)* ;
```

I know how to make it check that each block has at least two binary digits, but not the correct number.
Is there any way to make it more specific, using ANTLR?

Comment: This isn't a context free language, so you'll need to use some kind of semantic predicate. Perhaps you need to make the question more specific to ANTLR.

Comment: @rici What do you mean with more specific? I'm rather new to ANTLR. Is there something missing?

Comment: I meant, the only hint that you are looking for an ANTLR solution is the tag. I was about to answer (with a generic comment) when I saw the tag, so I made it a comment instead: you'll need to use an ANTLR-specific semantic predicate (and I'm not an ANTLR user so I can't give you much more guidance). You might want to read up on them and try it before editing the question.

Comment: @rici I've removed the generic 'parsing' tag and specified ANTLR in the question. Should have been more clear. I'll try to solve it with semantic predicates, thank you. I was trying to solve it on my own, but a nudge in the right direction is very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a semantic predicate it would look similar to this:

```
connections locals[int i] :
   {$i = 2;} BIN {check}? ({$i++;} ':' BIN {$check}?)* ;

BIN :
   [0-1]+ ;
```

where `check` is `$BIN.getText().length() == $i` (replace check to make the grammar work).

Another option would be to generate a parse tree visitor and to validate the BIN-Nodes while traversing the parse tree.